# how can I substite a , in the first field with awk when the fieldseparator is also a ,

Tags: awk

I have the following:

```
    "Facbook, Inc.","FB",232,232323
```

How can I substitute the `,` in the first field and then print the fields out with `OFS=,` and without the `"` ?

I would like to use awk.

Thanks

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output and what you've tried so far. If your input doesn't REALLY start with a bunch of spaces then get rid of them from the example you posted. Post a few lines of input/output that cover all of your use cases (e.g. cover all of these: do commas appear in other field? does 1 comma always appear in the first field? Can multiple commas appear in the first field? etc.). 1 line of sample input doesn't do much except show minimal effort.

Comment: HI, I have googled to my problem and realized that I had always add the FS="," . That was my mistake, because as default the fieldseparator is a blank and when I do the solution as RqinderSingh told me, the whole line is in $1 and so I can substitute the , as normal. @Ed Morton: To finish your question, in the first field there can be only , and in the other fields there can no be a , . All the lines look like this one example with other company names. Thanks a lot for your remark and correction of my originate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since sample expected output is not shown now, so can't be sure like this is what 100% required, try:

```
awk '{sub(/\,/,"",$1)} 1'  Input_file
```